# Implement a job scheduler which takes in a function f and an integer n, and calls f after n milliseconds

Tags: java, design-patterns, scheduled-tasks

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        solution(new Command() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                {
                    System.out.println("Hello World");
                }
            }
        }, 1000);

        // java 8
        solution(() -> System.out.println("Hello World"), 1000);
    }

    public static void solution(Command command, int n) {
        new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                command.execute();
            }
        }, n);

    }

    interface Command {
        public void execute();
    }

}
```

Can my solution be improved? I have used command pattern. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Imports

Use `import java.util.Timer;` and `import java.util.TimerTask;` at the top of the file.  This will allow you to simplify this:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
```

to this:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
```

which requires less typing and less reading, and so is arguably easier to understand.

---

## Naming

`command` is a decent name for a `Command` argument; `n` is a terrible name for an `int`.  Is that the count of the number of command objects you want submitted?  You have to consult the documentation for `Timer#schedule()` to discover that it is the number of milliseconds to wait before executing the command.

`milliseconds`, or `delay_ms` would be better names.

Similarly, `solution()` is a terrible name.  Solution to what?  `schedule_command()` might be a better choice.

---

## Reuse existing interfaces

The difference between `interface Command` and `interface Runnable` is that the former uses `execute()` where as the latter uses `run()`.  Oh, and the latter also adds the marker `@FunctionalInterface`.

By creating your own `Command` interface, you would force anyone who wants to use your scheduler, who already has classes that implement the standard `Runnable` interface, to add another interface to their class and forward the `execute()` method to the `run()` method (or vis versa).

---

## Timers and Threads

Every `Command` passed to `solution()` will cause the creation of a new `Timer()` object, with its own timer thread.  Each `Timer` object can schedule multiple tasks.  Additionally, all tasks owned by a `Timer` execute sequentially in the same thread, reducing concurrency issues.  Consider:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    solution( () -> { System.out.print("Hello from command #");
                      Thread.sleep(1);
                      System.out.print(i);
                      Thread.sleep(1);
                      System.out.println("!"); }, 1000 );
}
```

When executed, the output might become:

> Hello from command #Hello from command #0Hello from command #!
>   12!
>   !

If your scheduler used a single, common `Timer` object ...

```
private static Timer timer = new Timer();

public static void solution(Command command, int n) {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            command.execute();
        }
    }, n);
}
```

Then you would be guaranteed this output instead:

> Hello from command #0!
>   Hello from command #1!
>   Hello from command #2!

even though each `Command` was scheduled to run at the same time.

---

## Program Termination

From the [`Timer` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> After the last live reference to a Timer object goes away and all outstanding tasks have completed execution, the timer's task execution thread terminates gracefully (and becomes subject to garbage collection). **However, this can take arbitrarily long to occur.**

If you want your program to terminate quickly, you need to call [`.cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()) on all `Timer` objects you create, once the last scheduled task has completed (or at least been started).  This could be done by scheduling a task to cancel the task timer:

```
timer.schedule( () -> timer.cancel() );
```

---

## Job Control

You can [`.cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel()) a `TimerTask` before it has begun executing.  However, nothing is returned from `schedule()`, so the caller cannot cancel any submitted tasks.

---

## Better Implementation

Again, from the `Timer` documentation:

> Java 5.0 introduced the `java.util.concurrent` package and one of the concurrency utilities therein is the [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) ...

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService executor;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    ScheduledFuture<?> future = solution( () -> System.out.println("Hello World"), 1000);

    // Use future here, if desired.

    // Cleanup
    executor.shutdown();
    executor = null;
}

public static ScheduledFuture<?> solution(Runnable command, int delay_ms) {
    return executor.schedule( command, delay_ms, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
}
```